# Laravel using alternative path for views

Tags: laravel, view, routes, themes

I'am trying to return view from alternative folder

- Project Name

  - themes

    - admin

      - views
      - manage_users.blade.php

I tried

```
View::addLocation('/themes/admin/views');

View::addNamespace('theme', 'themes/admin/views');

return View::make('theme::manage_users');
```

But i keep getting error

`View [manage_users] not found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by removing the keyword `theme` so it became `return View::make('manage_users');`

Comment: Cool, pls mark your answer as the correct answer to close the issue.